# How to find unsaved documents at any given time in Windows using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How to find unsaved documents at any given time in Windows using vb.net?

I tried in Google but evertime answers are for retrieving unsaved documents instead of detecting.....

Comment: For any document, that's nearly impossible. You would have to detect every application for changes and that alone would be a task. There is a filewatcher class that can be used to determine when a file changes...

Comment: What's an unsaved document exactly?  Do you mean any data in any application that hasn't been saved to a file?  If you think that such a thing would be possible then I'm afraid you have some unrealistic expectations.